# Javascript regex time input mask - no plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input-mask

I am not able to use an input mask plugin and am attempting to create a time input mask of hh:mm with the meridian of am|pm. The input should not allow the user to start with alpha for example... but the pattern I've created (that I imagine could be simplified) will clear the entire value if the pattern is not exactly matched. This mask should validate on each keydown (or input in this case) so the following should be allowed:

0

02

02:

02:3

02:35

02:35 a

02:35 am

```
$('.time').on('input', function (e) {
    var input = $(this);
    var value = input.val();
    var pattern = /^(?!(^\d$)|(^\d\d$)|(^\d\d:$)|(^\d\d:\d$)|(^\d\d:\d\d$)|(^\d\d:\d\d\s$)|(^\d\d:\d\d\s(a|p)$)|(^\d\d:\d\d\s(am|pm)$)$).*/g;
    var newvalue = value.replace(pattern, '');
    input.val(newvalue);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ouk9mzad/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
$(selector).on('keypress', function (e) {

        var input = $(this);
        var value = input.val();
        var length = value.length + 1;
        var key = e.originalEvent.key;

        value += key;

        try {

            var pattern = '';

            if (length == 1 && value > 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            };

            if (length == 1) pattern = /\d/gi;
            else if (length == 2) pattern = /\d{2}/gi;
            else if (length == 3) pattern = /\d{2}:/gi;
            else if (length == 4) pattern = /\d{2}:\d/gi;
            else if (length == 5) pattern = /\d{2}:\d{2}/gi;
            else if (length == 6) pattern = /\d{2}:\d{2}\s/gi;
            else if (length == 7) pattern = /\d{2}:\d{2}\s(a|p)/gi;
            else if (length == 8) pattern = /\d{2}:\d{2}\s(a|p)m/gi;

            if (pattern == '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            };

            var ok = pattern.test(value);

            if (!ok) e.preventDefault();

        } catch (e) {
            HandleErrorMessages(e);
        };

    });
```

though it's not as dynamic as I'd like.

Comment: Maybe have an array of patterns and the index of the pattern you want to use matches the length variable?  Something like var patterns = ['', /\d/gi, /\d{2}/gi,/\d{2}:/gi] and so on.  That should clear up some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^\d(?:\d(?::(?:\d(?:\d(?:\s(?:(?:a|p)(?:m)?)?)??)?)?)?)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tyaeE1/1)